# hide validation errors or success message box on contact form 7

Tags: php, css, wordpress, validation, contact-form-7

I'm using plugin contact form 7 Version 5.1.1 and how do i hide display Validation errors or success message box from bottom form...

[image: validate error]

I already searched a lot of article that put this code

```
div.wpcf7-response-output {
    display: none !important;
}
```

I put that code in `./themes/myproject/style.css` but is not working

so how do I hide that validation errors or success message box from there

Comment: are you sure that that the style.css file is loaded? Are you sure that the "validation errors occurred" is a div with `wpcf7-response-output` class?

Comment: If you hide validation errors, how do users know they failed?

Answer (score 0):

```html
div.wpcf7-response-output, div.wpcf7-validation-errors { display: none !important; }
span.wpcf7-not-valid-tip { display: none; }
```

Comment: thank you for answering. but where do i put that code? i already paste it into   "./themes/myproject/style.css" but still not working

Comment: inside your theme's css file, or can use this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-css-and-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

```css
.wpcf7-response-output { display: none !important; }
```

Put above code in style.css

If the code above is not working then you can change `validation.css` from Contact Form 7.

```css
div.wpcf7-response-output, div.wpcf7-validation-errors { display: none !important; } 
span.wpcf7-not-valid-tip { display: none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Soltution to hide the success message.

First of all , Login in admin panel and select contact form 7 menu from left panel.

Next, edit form you want to change and go to bottom of it. You will get box named as “Additional Settings”.In the “Additional Settings” box, add following line of code.

```
on_sent_ok: "$('.wpcf7-mail-sent-ok').ajaxComplete(function(){$(this).delay(2000).fadeOut('slow');});"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slight variation if you want the field hidden initially when the page loads, but do want it to show where there is a validation error.

```
.wpcf7 form.init .wpcf7-response-output {
    display: none
}
```

Source, Contact Form 7 Support: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/contact-form-7-5-2-validation-message-always-visible/

In my case, styling gave this (empty) field a background color and border which made it look like an empty, unlabeled input field. It looked like something the user was supposed to fill in, but could not. And it just looked bad.
Adding the above CSS hides the field unless:

- there is a validation error
- the form was successfully sent (this field is also used to show the success message.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late to the party.  But you can also just add to the functions.php of your theme/child theme :

```
add_filter('wpcf7_form_response_output', '__return_empty_string');
```